# How to apply changes to keyboard layout without reboot

Tags: settings, keyboard, reboot

After playing with keyboard layout at */system/usr/keylayout/..* the changes are take effect only after a system restart. How to apply the changes immediately ?

**Additional details**
Phone : Samsung galaxy chat - gt B5330
OS : ICS (stock) ,rooted
file correspond to physical keyboard : bcm_keypad_v2.kl

Comment: Switching to another keyboard and then back might work.  If you see the keyboard in your running apps/services, stopping it and then performing an action that would bring it up might also work.

Comment: Thans for the suggestion. Unfortunatelu it's not working. it's a built in PHYSCIAL KEYBOARD.

Comment: Oh, I see.  You might need to unload and reload a driver / kernel module but it's hard to say.  Can you add the details of your device and software version to the question?

Comment: Updated. Can we use *modprobe* or *services* command as in linux.

Comment: @totti Android is based on linux and there are terminal apps available. I don't know those commands but it might work. Best way to find out is to try! :)